# Generate Random elements without duplicate

Tags: javascript, random

I am trying to make a **Random Number Generator**.

I made a code and it does work well.

```js
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click',()=>{
  generate(1,45,6)
});

function generate(min, max, count){
  const arr = [];

  if(min >= max) return;
  if(max - min + 1 < count) return;

  while (arr.length < count) {
    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    let flag = arr.every((i) => {
      return i === num ? false : true;
    });
    if (flag) {
      arr.push(num);
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Gen</button>
```

But my algorithm's time complexity is **O(n)**. (I am not sure, I didn't calculate it strictly)

I hope to reduce the time complexity if I can.

And, I guess my above code can be compacted, but I can't.

**Summary What I Want**

1. To reduce the time complexity if it can be
2. To make it compacted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `Set` (which will take care of duplicates) instead of an array and keep checking its size until you have all the numbers you want:

```js
document.querySelector('#btn').addEventListener('click',()=>{
  generate(1,45,6)
});

function generate(min, max, count){
  const s = new Set();

  if(min >= max) return;
  if(max - min + 1 < count) return;

  while (s.size < count) { // O(1)
    let num = Math.floor(Math.random() * max) + min;
    s.add(num); // O(1)
  }
  console.log(Array.from(s));
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Gen</button>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for!